# How to programmatically change button size without accumulating a huge number of constraints?

Tags: ios, swift

I tested the viability of modifying constraints with the following code

```
sortButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5.0).isActive = true
sortButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500.0).isActive = true
```

I thought the 500 would override the 5. However, the console said there was a conflict, and it would break the 500 constraint to stay with the width of 5. I know I can disable the 5.0 one by setting "isActive" to false. However, this isn't the same as actually removing the old constraint. This would be a problem if I keep changing the button size to arbitrary values over the course of running an app. The number of constraints will just keep growing and growing endlessly. What's the right way to change the button size an arbitrary number of times? I tried using the frame as well, and that had no effect.

Comment: One potential solution is to keep a "quantized" array of possible constraint values, e.g. [1, 2, 3... 300]. Then I pick the closest value to the size I need, from this list of constraints. This way the number of constraints stays constant.

Comment: I could also remove the button and add a new one every time?

Comment: You only need a single constraint. Keep a reference to the constraint in a property and simply change its `constant` as required. You can even animate the change.

Comment: ahh I see; thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make refrence of widthanchor
like

```
weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? 
widthConstraint = sortButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5.0)
```

Now you can manipulate this variable

```
widthConstraint?.isActive = true
```

or

```
widthConstraint?.constant = 500
```

if in UIStackView

```
yourStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```